# How can I "close" a Task from the REST API/Apex

Tags: apex, rest-api, picklist, tasks

Since all picklist values for the Status field on Tasks are configurable I don't think I can simply set the Status to "Completed" as that picklist value could have been deleted/renamed.

I tried getting the picklist values for the Status field, but when I list the picklist values with the REST API or via Apex, I don't seem to get this information. All I get is Label, Value, isActive, and isDefaultValue. Is there any way to know if one of the picklist values is considered closed? or to reliably set a Task to "closed" without knowing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to query the object TaskStatus to pull the list of all status values, along with a field IsClosed to tell you which values would mark a task as closed. Your query would look something like this.

```
SELECT MasterLabel, IsClosed FROM TaskStatus WHERE IsClosed = true
```

You can then execute the query using the standard query endpoint (details [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index_Left.htm#CSHID=dome_query.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fdome_query.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) in case you're not familiar with it).

More info on the TaskStatus object can be found here http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_taskstatus.htm